# display a div/span only after $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] has been executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, prestashop

I tried to approach it numerous ways, but somehow I'm not able to figure it out. Maybe you guys can help me?

I need to display a certain div/span or whatever container to display a text after page goes back via

```
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

The reason why I need such a wierd approach to display something is that I'm using a href/GET combination to run a PHP function when my link gets klicked. (submit button is in use by another function/module so I can't use that )

HTML part

```
    <p id="show_project">
        <a id="add_to_project" name="add_to_project" href="?function">
        Add to project
        </a>
    </p>
```

PHP function part

```
    $this->getProductinfo();
    if (isset($_GET['function'])){
        $this->getSQLQuery($_GET['function']);
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
```

Any ideas ?

BR's

Comment: I would handle the original link click with ajax, but if you cannot do that, you could do a double re-direct, first to the page you want to show temporarily and then to the original referrer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add a message to your header() call

```
$this->getProductinfo();
if (isset($_GET['function'])){
    $this->getSQLQuery($_GET['function']);
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'?msg=We got a message');
}
```

Get the message

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!empty($_GET['msg'])){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = $_GET['msg'];
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    die;
}
else{
    if (!empty($_SESSION['msg'])){
        $msg = $_SESSION['msg'];
        unset($_SESSION['msg']);
    }
}
    ?>

<?php
/* Later in the document */
echo '<div>' . $msg . '</div>';

?>
```

You will need to sanitise and validate the $_GET variable

[borrowed from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789231/remove-get-parameter-in-url-after-processing-is-finishednot-using-post-php)

Comment: it's a good approach but if a user will refresh a page the massege starts to stack and get longer and logner. Any way to prevent that ?

Comment: I got it working by using sessions too, but your solution is more - how to say it, elegant :) Thanks