# How to remove $_GET parameters from URL after one time use

Tags: get

Could you please help me? After clinking the button when i reload the page,  i need to remove the GET parameter and not to show the thanks massage again.

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['status'])){
$thanks="Hi, Thank you for this single click!";
}
?>

<html>
<a href="?status=data" ><button>Giving Thanks</button></a>
<h4><?php echo $thanks;?></h4>
</html>
```

Comment: $_GET is not the appropriate scope for this kind of thing. Maybe consider $_SESSION scope or $_COOKIE. Also, your code as it is in the examples contains a Script injection vulnerability so look that up too.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your html body.

```
<script>    
    if(typeof window.history.pushState == 'function') {
        window.history.pushState({}, "Hide", '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>');
    }
</script>
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871363/6225257

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to the following.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['status'])) {
    $thanks = 'Hi, Thank you for this single click!';
}
?>

<html>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="data" />
    <button type="submit">Giving Thanks</button>
</form>
<?php if(!empty($thanks)) : ?>
    <h4><?php echo $thanks;?></h4>
<?php endif; ?>
</html>
```